# All of the containers stopped in hyperledger fabric - fabric-ca example in fabric-samples

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am running fabric-ca example in fabric-samples on 20 Azure servers having each service like peers, orderers running on different machine.
Now recently all of the services got stopped. That means all of the peers, orderers, ica containers each running on different machine got stopped.

Below are the steps that I followed.

1. I restarted the ica-org0, ica-org1, ica-org2 containers which created new org0-ca-chain, org1-ca-chain and org2-ca-chain certificates.
2. Then i copied those certificates on peers and orderer machines and then restarted the containers. However while doing so, I restarted all of the peers but mistakenly I did recreate the container for peer1-org1 instead of restart.
3. Now while all of the other containers except peer1-org1 are restarted but all of these peers are looking for peer1-org1 to communicate which is newly created with new org1-ca-chain certificate.
4. Below is the peer1-org1 log,

> [gossip/comm] authenticateRemotePeer -> WARN 1d4 Identity store
>   rejected 10.64.37.229:49692 : failed classifying identity: Unable to
>   extract msp.Identity from peer Identity [gossip/comm] GossipStream ->
>   ERRO 1d5 Authentication failed: failed classifying identity: Unable to
>   extract msp.Identity from peer Identity

5. Below is the peer1-org2 log which is running on 10.64.37.229,

> [gossip/comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 18e8[0m Failed obtaining
>   connection for peer1-org1:7051, PKIid:[130 169 200 147 151 98 112 245
>   155 234 176 88 178 195 88 136 118 154 94 91 90 37 108 90 11 182 83 100
>   124 97 165 32] reason: Authentication failure
>       [33m2018-06-21 00:00:12.581 UTC [gossip/comm] createConnection -> WARN 18e9[0m Remote endpoint claims to be a different peer, expected
>   [130 169 200 147 151 98 112 245 155 234 176 88 178 195 88 136 118 154
>   94 91 90 37 108 90 11 182 83 100 124 97 165 32] but got [163 170 196
>   200 27 103 168 165 139 214 157 20 189 220 36 72 37 81 44 18 9 226 194
>   227 210 149 141 128 30 214 113 200]

6. Now i want to have peer1-org1 to be running as it was before getting stopped. How do I do this?.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing the same problem